# Redirect to Area always gives 404 or wrong Redirect

Tags: c#, redirect, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm trying to make an application that has an area where you only can get in when u are logged in.

[image]

For some reason when I redirect to my area after the login this fails. Resulting in following Route generation

```
 var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
 if (result.Succeeded)
 {
    _logger.LogInformation(1, "User logged in.");
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Dashboard" });
  }
```

Route that the redirect makes:
http://localhost:23490/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FDashboard%2FHome

And if I surfto the link directly (like so) http://localhost:23490/Dashboard/Home/Index

I get an 404

The controller I'm trying to reach is defined like so

```
  //[Authorize]
[Area("Dashboard")]
[Route("Dashboard/[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Dashboard
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I checked everything I could find about this topic but as this is very new there is not much information on this.

What I have tried

- Checked if view & controller are defined correctly, they are
- Checked if the routing is correct, seems like it to me

  ```
          app.UseMvc(routes =>
      {
          routes.MapRoute(name: "areaRoute",
              template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

          routes.MapRoute(
              name: "default",
              template: "{controller=Route}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
      });
  ```
- Tried to create a custom redirect for action (which failed)

I'm hoping someone can assist me on this topic. 
Thanks !

Comment: Why do you use `[Route("Dashboard/[controller]")]` on top of controller? Did you try without this?

Comment: No i did not try this, but the setup i used was based on another SO question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make your example work, you should mark `[HttpGet("Index")]` your `Index` method

```
[Area("Dashboard")]
[Route("Dashboard/[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Dashboard
    [HttpGet("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

So here your `HomeController` work in RESTFUL way, so you could use `public IActionResult Get()` or `[HttpPost] public IActionResult Post()`. If this what you want, you could achieve it in more generic way

```
[Area("Dashboard")]
[Route("[area]/[controller]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Dashboard
    [HttpGet("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

If you do not want RESTFUL for you dashboard you shourd remove `[HttpGet("Index")]` and add `[action]` to you controller attribute, so if would be like this

```
[Area("Dashboard")]
[Route("[area]/[controller]/[action]")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Dashboard
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

If this suite your purposes you can omit `[Route("[area]/[controller]/[action]")]` entirely because this is default convention.